# I'm getting an Incompatible pointer types warning

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I'm trying to create an extension for an AIR application and have been following documentation on Adobe's website and some other examples and everything looks correct but I don't know enough about Objective C to know why I'm getting this warning.

```
#import "FlashRuntimeExtensions.h"

@import Contacts;
@import UIKit;

CNAuthorizationStatus contactStatus;
CNContactStore * contactStore;
CNContactFetchRequest * request;
NSMutableArray * contacts;
NSArray * fullContactList;

FREObject HasContactListAccess(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc) {
    uint32_t statusResult = true;

    if(contactStatus == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied){
        statusResult = false;
    }

    FREObject returnBoolean = nil;
    FRENewObjectFromBool(statusResult,&returnBoolean);

    return returnBoolean;
}

FREObject GetAllContacts(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc){
    contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        contacts = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSError * fetchError;
        request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:@[CNContactIdentifierKey, [CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]]];

        BOOL success = [contactStore enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError usingBlock:^(CNContact * _Nonnull contact, BOOL * stop) {
            [contacts addObject:contact];
        }];

        if(!success) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", fetchError);
        }

        fullContactList = [contacts copy];
    }];



    FREObject contactsObject = NULL;
    FRENewObject((const uint8_t*)"Array", 0, NULL, &contactsObject, nil);

    return contactsObject;
}

void AIRContextInitializer(void* extData, const uint8_t* ctxType, FREContext ctx, uint32_t* numFunctionsToSet, const FRENamedFunction** functionsToSet){
    contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    *numFunctionsToSet = 2;
    FRENamedFunction* func = (FRENamedFunction*)malloc(sizeof(FRENamedFunction) * *numFunctionsToSet);

    func[0].name = (const uint8_t*)"hasContactListAccess";
    func[0].functionData = NULL;
    func[0].function = &HasContactListAccess;

    func[1].name = (const uint8_t*)"getAllContacts";
    func[1].functionData = NULL;
    func[1].function = &GetAllContacts;

    *functionsToSet = func;
}

void AIRContextFinalizer(FREContext ctx) {
    return;
}

void AIRExtensionInitializer(void** extDataToSet, FREContextInitializer* ctxInitializerToSet, FREContextFinalizer* ctxFinalizerToSet) {
    *extDataToSet = NULL;
    *ctxInitializerToSet = &AIRContextInitializer;
}
```

The warnings are showing on lines 59 and 63:

```
func[0].function = &HasContactListAccess;
func[1].function = &GetAllContacts;
```

Comment: What is the full warning? — be more specific (It should give you type incompatibility).

Comment: Maybe your functions are missing a parameter `FREObject argv[]`?

Comment: Sorry, I must have deleted the error. Here is the exact error I'm getting Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'FREFunction' (aka 'FREObject (*)(FREContext, void *, uint32_t, FREObject *)') from 'FREObject (*)(FREContext, void *, uint32_t)'

Comment: @Willeke you were correct. I was missing the FREObject argv[] in the functions. Thank you.